# How to perform insert/delete/update operations in a linked list of vertices in orientdb?

Tags: orientdb

In our orientdb database we would like to store a sequence of vertices ordered by date/time and connected by edges with each other as follows:

```
... -> e1 -> e2 -> e3 -> e4 -> e5 -> ... 
     12:01 12:02 12:03 12:04 12:05
```

The problem is: an event may also occur subsequently e.g. in the above example we would now like to add a new vertex with time 12:02:30. Therefore the vertices/edges need to be rearranged accordingly. Same for delete operations. How can we do this (efficiently) in orientdb?

Comment: Hi, what version are you using? Thx

Comment: I'am using version 3.0.3